# User changing terminology

Tags: discussion, editing

I have spotted that a user is editing old posts and changing every occurrence of "the Hawaiian earring" with "the infinite earring". As far as i know this is not standard terminology. I am not aware of any way to flag these edits, or if that is even the right approach. How should one approach this?

Comment: These edits are absolutely unnecessary and should be reversed for searching purposes.

Comment: I've left a comment under one of their posts to explain this.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire:  As a side issue, would the situation be different had the change simply been a correction to the official spelling of "Hawaiʻian"?  Would the addition of the missing letter (okina) break searches or in some other way be inappropriate?

Comment: @RayButterworth That would be completely superfluous. And especially so when editing old posts.

Comment: I would argue that the change---without discussion---is inappropriate.  However, @TheSimpliFire, I think it is slightly more nuanced than your comment indicates (for the record, I agree with you, and think that this is a tempest in a teapot, but there is room for some conversation here).

Comment: @XanderHenderson I concur as this is quite a unique case. Note I commented above prior to knowing about the Twitter thread shared an hour later in the duplicate meta discussion.